# Methods not compatible, but no complains when defining them

Tags: typescript

For a few hours no, I am trying to figure this out, but I can't...

Consider the following code:

```
type listenerPayload<TExpectedData extends object = {}, TExpectedResponse extends object | boolean = boolean> = {
  request: TExpectedData,
  response: TExpectedResponse
}

type payloadCollection = {
  [key in string]: listenerPayload<object, object | boolean>
}

type clientConnectionPayload = {
  'broadcast.orderCreated': listenerPayload<{
        order: any
  }>
}

interface generalTransferData {
  status?: boolean;
  _relayed?: any;
  error?: any;
  [key: string]: any;
}

class BasicConnection<
    TBroadcasters extends payloadCollection = payloadCollection
> {
  sendPromise<
    TMessage extends keyof TBroadcasters,
    TData extends TBroadcasters[TMessage]['request'],
    TResponse extends (generalTransferData | generalTransferData & Exclude<TBroadcasters[TMessage]['response'], boolean>)
  >(action: TMessage, data?: TData): Promise<TResponse> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      });
  }
}

class ExtendedConnection< 
    TBroadcasters extends payloadCollection = payloadCollection
> extends BasicConnection<
    TBroadcasters & clientConnectionPayload
> {
  sendPromise<
        TMessage extends keyof TBroadcasters,
        TData extends TBroadcasters[TMessage]['request'],
        TResponse extends (generalTransferData | generalTransferData & Exclude<TBroadcasters[TMessage]['response'], boolean>)
    >(action: TMessage, data?: TData): Promise<TResponse> {
     /** Extend the funcitonality with something additional */
     return super.sendPromise(action, data);
  }
}

const ExtendedConnectionInstance = new ExtendedConnection();

/** The two classes give no errors at all, everything works as expected, however */
interface nodeFormOptions {
    /** the name of the event to send data via */
    event: string;

    /** the connection to use to send the data */
    connection: BasicConnection<any>;
}

const nodeFormOption: nodeFormOptions = {
  event: 'broadcast.orderCreated',
  connection: ExtendedConnectionInstance // why am I getting error here that the two "sendPromise" methods are not compatible, but no complains in the class body itself
}
```

I am trying to create two classes, one provides type hinting, and some additional functionality for the other one, thus I am using extension. When defining these classes, and using them separately, everything works as expected. However, when I am trying to use the `extended` version of the class, in place of the more `generic` version, for an interface, that requires the `generic` version, typescript starts to complain:

> Type 'ExtendedConnection' is not assignable to type 'BasicConnection'.
> Types of property 'sendPromise' are incompatible.
> Type '<TMessage extends string, TData extends object, TResponse extends generalTransferData | (generalTransferData & object)>(action: TMessage, data?: TData | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TMessage extends string | number | symbol, TData extends any, TResponse extends any>(action: TMessage, data?: TData | undefined) => Promise'.
> Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
> Type 'TMessage' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)

Why am I getting this error??? What is wrong here???

Comment: Please consider adhering to TS naming conventions when posting example code; interface and other type names should be in UpperCamelCase, instances of classes and other variable names should be in lowerCamelCase, and generic type parameter names should be single uppercase characters like `T` (although this convention is less universal).

Comment: You are getting the error because `nodeFormOption.connection.sendPromise(1, "x")` should be allowed, but `extendedConnectionInstance.sendPromise()` only accepts a `string` as its first argument and an `object | undefined` for its second argument, so the assignment is invalid. See [here](//tsplay.dev/we4ZYW).  Note that the fact that the class definitions work has to do with differeing generics; obviously you cannot assign an `Array<string>` to `Array<number>` even though every method in `Array` is the same as itself. Does that make sense? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, it makes sense, what is missing, is the way I can make this error-less (except the obvious type-casting to `any`). How can I tell `nodeFormOptions` that it should except something that is or is derived from `BasicConnection`, disregarding the generic type it receives? or something like this is even possible?

Comment: That sounds like a followup question; the post asks why it’s happening and not how to work around it. I wouldn’t know how to answer this without significantly more time and effort. If you need that part answered then please [edit] the question to make that clear.